# Auto reconnect to RabbitMQ cluster after server restart

Tags: rabbitmq, docker, google-compute-engine, fault-tolerance

I have master-slave configuration of RabbitMQ. As two Docker containers, with dynamic internal IP (changed on every restart).

Clustering works fine on clean run, but if one of servers got restarted it cannot reconnect to the cluster:

```
rabbitmqctl join_cluster --ram rabbit@master
Clustering node 'rabbit@slave' with 'rabbit@master' ...
Error: {ok,already_member}
```

And following:

```
rabbitmqctl cluster_status
Cluster status of node 'rabbit@slave' ...
[{nodes,[{disc,['rabbit@slave']}]}]
```

says that node not in a cluster.

Only way I found it remove this node, and only then try to rejoin cluster, like:

```
rabbitmqctl -n rabbit@master forget_cluster_node rabbit@slave
rabbitmqctl join_cluster --ram rabbit@master
```

That works, but doesn't look good for me. I believe there should be better way to rejoin cluster, than forgetting and join again. I see there is a command `update_cluster_nodes` also, but seems that this something different, not sure if it could help.

What is correct way to rejoin cluster on container restart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize that this has been opened for a year but I though I would answer just in case it might help someone.

I believe that this issue has been resolved in a recent RabbitMQ release.

I implemented a [Dockerized RabbitMQ Cluster](https://github.com/EtienneDufresne/rabbitmq-docker-cluster) using the [Rabbit management 3.6.5 image](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/) and my nodes are able to auto rejoin the cluster on container or Docker host restart.